# AngularJS directive with ui-mask

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating a directive to validate the age of a user and I am using it in combination with ui-mask.  The html for my input is as such:

```
<input id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="owner.dateOfBirth" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" required ui-mask="99/99/9999" minimum-age="18">
```

and the directive (copied from the blacklist directive example here on stackoverflow):

```
angular.module('Pensco.AEW.Directives')
.directive('minimumAge', function (){
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
            var minimumAge = parseInt(attr.minimumAge, 10),
                minDate = new Date(),
                monthsToSubtract = 12 * minimumAge;

            // subtract the months from today
            minDate.setMonth(minDate.getMonth() - monthsToSubtract);

            //For DOM -> model validation
            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                var valid = isValid(value);

                ngModel.$setValidity('minimumAge', valid);

                return value;
            });

            //For model -> DOM validation
            ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {
                var valid = isValid(value);

                ngModel.$setValidity('minimumAge', valid);

                return value;
            });

            function cleanMask(value) {
                var parts;

                if (!value) { return; }

                parts = value.split('/');

                parts[0] = checkLength(parts[0], 2, 'm');
                parts[1] = checkLength(parts[1], 2, 'd');
                parts[2] = checkLength(parts[2], 4, 'y');

                return parts.join('/');
            }

            function checkLength(value, len, character) {
                if (value.length > len) {
                    value = value.slice(0, - 1);
                } else if (value.length < len) {
                    value = value + character;
                }

                return value;
            }

            function isValid(value) {
                var cleanedValue = cleanMask(value),
                    dob = new Date(cleanedValue);

                // if the date is valid then compare it to calculated min date
                if (isDate(dob)) {
                    return dob <= minDate;
                }

                return false;
            }

            function isDate(value) {
                return value instanceof Date && isFinite(value)
            }
        }
    };
});
```

The issue is that value is that when the user types a number such as 0, value is set to "0mm/dd/yyyy" as it appears that ui-mask has not removed the placeholder character yet to make it "0m/dd/yyyy".  ui-mask has its priority set to 100, so I set the priority of this directive to -1000 thinking it might have the mask finish processing before processing my directive.  After my directive is completed it appears that ui-mask finishes processing and removes the placeholder character.

I added a couple of methods to clean and validate the dates, which works, and yet, I have to believe there is a cleaner way to handle it.  Any ideas on how I can my directive to fire after ui-mask is done processing?

Comment: angular directives replaced jquery plugins, you have to initialize ui-mask into the link method.

Comment: open the developer tool and you will see a error TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I found a issue in your code.In checklength methos throw TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I have change the code to

```
function checkLength(value, len, character) {
            if(value!=undefined)
            {
            if (value.length > len) {
                value = value.slice(0, - 1);
            } else if (value.length < len) {
                value = value + character;
            }
            }

            return value;
        }
```

Check this [Working Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/e8Nj3/19/) which is working correctly.